# Is it better approach to declare and initialize a bigdecimal number with "new" keyword or static method?

Tags: java

I have to declare and initialize BigDecimal wrapper object several times in project. Then which is better approach either by java Code:

```
BigDecimal num=new BigDecimal("123");
```

or in `NumberUtils` class there is already a static method available as

```
public static BigInteger createBigInteger(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new BigInteger(str);
}

BigDecimal num=NumberUtils.createBigInteger("123");
```

Plese tell me, which is better approach as we compared performance wise(memory and speed).

Comment: A constructor is in principle just another static method, as far as the caller is concerned. In addition, you can be pretty sure that NumberUtils static method will ultimativly invoke the constructor anyway in most, if not all,  cases. Thus your question is utterly menaingless.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. However assuming you mean `BigDecimal` rather than `BigInteger` throughout, there is little point in your static method. It just defers the possible NPE to a later point in your calling code, that will probably be harder to debug.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well clearly `createBigInteger` is doing more work - it's checking for nullity, when you know the argument value won't be null anyway. That's only a tiny, tiny bit of extra work though - almost *certain* to be irrelevant in reality.

I'd be surprised if this were really a *performance* concern anyway though - have you identified this to be a bottleneck in your code? If not, write the most *readable* code - which for me would be the constructor call. Then identify what your performance requirements are, and test your whole system against them. If it's not performing well enough, write more tests or use a profiler to identify which areas are causing problems.

Another alternative would be to use the `BigDecimal(int)` constructor - why bother parsing a string?

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(123);
```

If you wanted, you could even have this as a constant, so you could reuse the object:

```
private static final BigDecimal DEFAULT_FOOBAR_VALUE = new BigDecimal(123);

// In a method or whatever...
BigDecimal num = DEFAULT_FOOBAR_VALUE;
```

Aside from performance, I'd argue this is *clearer* as it indicates the reason for the constant.

Comment: +1 90% for the effort, 10% because I want to see how SO prints 1mln rep

Comment: I think the constant is the way to go if performance is the objective - it's a good fit because BigDecimal is immutable.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am looking in this code for performance only and i have to initialize BigDecimal with String as per my project requirement. then which approach is reccomended?

Comment: @AnkitKumar: You can still use the constant approach with the string constructor. But unless you've actually proved that this is even slightly a performance bottleneck, I suspect you're wasting your time thinking about one versus the other.

Comment: Question was specifically using a String it may even be variable

Comment: Actually, using the string constructor is considered good practice when dealing with BigDecimal as explained here: https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/four-common-pitfalls-of-the-bigdecimal-class-and-how-to-avoid-them

Comment: @MatthiasGüntert: It's considered better than using the constructor accepting a `double`, for the reasons given in that post. I don't see anything in that post that would argue against calling the constructor accepting an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following constant to initialize BigDecimal.

```
 BigDecimal.ZERO
 BigDecimal.ONE
 BigDecimal.Ten
BigDecimal average = BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show caution when using a decimal value in the initialization of a `BigDecimal`.

```
BigDecimal onePercentPlusABit = new BigDecimal(0.01);
```

is not equal to

```
BigDecimal onePercentExact = new BigDecimal("0.01");
```

and this:

```
BigDecimal(0.01).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

is significantly slower than

```
BigDecimal("0.01");
```